# how to get previous year (month december) and month showing current month in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have list of datetime value. How to select previous year just for december only.

For example:

```
Current month = May 2016
Previous year of december = Dec 2015
(it will display data from dec 2015 to may 2016)

if Current month = May 2017
Previous year of december = Dec 2016 and so on.
(it will display data from dec 2015 to may 2016)
```

Any idea ? Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
*
FROM
TableName
WHERE
TableName.Date BETWEEN CONVERT(DATE,CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEPART(YYYY,GETDATE())-1)+'-12-'+'01') AND GETDATE()
```

Comment: it's not work. Display error 'DATEFROMPARTS' is not a recognized built-in function name. I'm using sql 2008

Comment: Ok..i thought its 2012 :)

Comment: Yes, but your answer is already so close to what i want. But I'm still newbie in sql 2012 syntax. Can you help to give me in 2008 version   :(

Answer (score 1):

Below query will give the required output :-

```
declare @val as date='2016-05-19'

select concat(datename(MM,DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,@val), -1)),'   ',datepart(YYYY,DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,@val), -1)))
```

output : december 2015

Answer (score 0):

You can subtract the month number:

```
select dateadd(month, - month(val), val)
```